# permutations errors in printing?

Tags: c, arrays

There is two functions one swaps integers in the array and the other recursion gets all permutations without reputations. But it prints 0,1 for all permutations. l is 0 and r is (size of the array-1).

the input of array a is {0,1,1} for permute.

```
void swap(int a[], int first, int second, int r)
{
    if (second > r)
    {
        int tempp = a[first];
        a[first] = a[second];
        a[second] = tempp;
    }

}


void permute(int a[], int l, int r)
{
    int i;
    if (l == r){
        for (int i = 0; i < l; i++)
        {
            printf("%d",a[i]);
            if (i == (r - 1))
            {
                printf("\n");
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        for (i = l; i <= r; i++)
        {
            swap(a,l, i,r);
            permute(a, l+1, r);
            swap(a,l, i,r);
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: It's not clear what your question is.  What is your output, and how is it different from what you expect?

Comment: output is the first two digits of the permutations not the 3 digits.

Answer (score 0):

The condition `second > r` in `swap()` will always be false due to the condition in the second `for` statement in `permute()`.

Remove the harmful condition and add range check if you need.

```
void swap(int a[], int first, int second, int r)
{
    if (0 <= first && first <= r && 0 <= second && second <= r) /* range check */
    {
        int tempp = a[first];
        a[first] = a[second];
        a[second] = tempp;
    }

}
```

Change `for (int i = 0; i < l; i++)` to `for (int i = 0; i <= l; i++)`
and change `if (i == (r - 1))` to `if (i == l)` if you want to print all elements in the array instead of omitting the last one.

Comment: The Swap change actually did the permutation. but second change still omits the last one.

Comment: and it does not do anything, it deletes the spaces.

Comment: What do you mean? This code seems [working well](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/RfxaChwrZ4o8jWjK) except for printing duplicate sequences.

Comment: when i run it, the output is just one line of the output i was getting at the beginning.